# Changing the UIButton Images get button postion changed

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am changing the UIButton image on button click but it gets postion changes from original to left side. I don't know why  this is happening.
Below is the button. When I select the second button, it changes image and gets to the left side. How do I fix this error ?

Below is my code

```
  -(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction{


UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radiogreen.png"];

UIImage *buttonImageOne=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiowhite.png"];


[locationOneButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[locationOneButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[locationThreeButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[locationTwoButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[locationFourButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[locationFiveButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[locationSixButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];


resturantLocation=@"Common Man - Bedford, MA";
```

}

Comment: Your images might not be the same dimensions

Comment: @Eric yes you are right they are not of the same dimensions

Comment: In that case is that why the image seems to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not hundred percent sure about your case but it usually happen because of transparent space in both images, please overlap your images in Photoshop and make sure both images should have same margins and also should be of same size.

Answer (score 0):

`setImage` wont stretch your image to fill frame of your button, it will set to center of button.

Make sure your image size and frame of your button is equal.

Else you can use `setBackgroundImage` which is will stretch your image to fill frame of button.